# consolidating numbers along columns in xslt

Tags: templates, xslt

I want to convert an .xml file into another .xml file of the same schema with xslt. The reason is to consolidate some time-based measurements stored in the input file into new time base to the output file. The xml file is a dump from rrdtool, which is not able to convert it, so I try it with xslt.
I've used XSLT several times and I got the declarative ideas behind it, but in this specific problem I'm unable to cope it, even don't know where to start:

The input xml data is organized by measurements of 1 second for each sensor. In this example the header is stripped of, there are 60 timestamps (e.g. 14:09.00 .01 ... .59) for 2 sensors, but in reality are thousands of timestamps :

```
input.xml:

<timestamp>
  <sensor>1.1</sensor>
  <sensor>2.3</sensor>
</timestamp>
<timestamp>
  <sensor>1.2</sensor>
  <sensor>2.2</sensor>
</timestamp>
...
<timestamp>
  <sensor>1.9</sensor>
  <sensor>NaN</sensor>
</timestamp>
```

The resulting output xml data shall be organized by measurement of 1 minute, so each 60 input timestamps are consolidated by average into 1 new timestamp (e.g. 3600 seconds into 60 minutes) still including the 2 sensors:

```
output.xml:

<timestamp>
  <sensor>1.5</sensor>
  <sensor>2.1</sensor>
</timestamp>
```

The example above is very much minimized, practically I deal within one file with 10.000 of timestamps and 2 up to 24 sensors - so "harcoding" is not a good solution, it shall be an xslt-1.0-template based solution.
I don't know how to grap several sensor data, because they are organized in columns (the "sensor" tag) encapsulated within the rows (the "timestamp" tag).
I don't know how to store the intermediate values for consolidation for each sensor.
Sometimes there are invalid measurement values "NaN" are in the Input file, which shall be ignored in consolidation as long as none is valid, than the output value is also "NaN".

So a lot of ?????

Thanks
   Achim

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the number of sensors for each timestamp is the same, for each XML document. In this case, try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="timestamps">
      <timestamp>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="timestamp[1]/sensor"/>
      </timestamp>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="sensor">
      <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()"/>
      <xsl:variable name="sensors" select="count(//timestamp/sensor[$position][. != 'NaN'])"/>
      <sensor>
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$sensors &gt; 0">
               <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(//timestamp/sensor[$position][. != 'NaN']) div $sensors, '0.00')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
               <xsl:text>NaN</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
      </sensor>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following XSLT (for just 3 timestamps for 2 sensors)

```
<timestamps>
   <timestamp>
      <sensor>1.1</sensor>
      <sensor>2.3</sensor>
   </timestamp>
   <timestamp>
      <sensor>1.2</sensor>
      <sensor>2.2</sensor>
   </timestamp>
   <timestamp>
      <sensor>1.9</sensor>
      <sensor>NaN</sensor>
   </timestamp>
</timestamps>
```

The following output is produced:

```
<timestamp>
   <sensor>1.40</sensor>
   <sensor>2.25</sensor>
</timestamp>
```

**EDIT:** If you want to consolidate certain numbers of timestamps together, rather than all of them at once, here is another XSLT style sheet you can try (Note, I have removed the un-necessary **xsl:choose** statement from this version).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:param name="group" select="2"/>

   <xsl:template match="timestamps">
      <timestamps>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="timestamp[position() mod $group = 1]"/>
      </timestamps>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="timestamp">
      <timestamp>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="sensor" />
      </timestamp>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="sensor">
      <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()"/>
      <xsl:variable name="sensors" select="1 + count(../following-sibling::*[not(position() >= $group)]/sensor[$position][. != 'NaN'])"/>
      <sensor>
         <xsl:value-of select="format-number((. + sum(../following-sibling::*[not(position() >= $group)]/sensor[$position][. != 'NaN'])) div $sensors, '0.00')"/>
      </sensor>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In this case, I have parameterised the number of timestamps you want to consolidate, and have set it to 2 for this example.

When applied to the same XML, the following is output:

```
<timestamps>
   <timestamp>
     <sensor>1.15</sensor>
     <sensor>2.25</sensor>
   </timestamp>
   <timestamp>
      <sensor>1.90</sensor>
      <sensor>NaN</sensor>
   </timestamp>
</timestamps>
```

Comment: Duuuh, I've just tried it, works perfect, beside that I've not written that I need each 60 input timestamps consolidated into 1 new output timestamp (60 seconds into 1 minute). So at the moment a file with 3600 timestams will be consolidated into 1 new, but I need it into 60 for the 60 minutes... sorry was not good described. So a kind of restart is needed to start counting again after 60 are reached and creating a new output timestamp element.

Answer (score 0):

**This simple transformation** (no `xsl:choose`, no `xsl:when`, no `xsl:otherwize`, just one template):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:variable name="vNumSensors">
      <xsl:for-each select="/*/*">
        <xsl:sort select="count(sensor)"
             data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() =1">
          <xsl:value-of select="count(sensor)"/>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:variable>

     <xsl:template match="/">
         <timestamp>
           <xsl:for-each select=
              "(//node())[not(position() > $vNumSensors)]">
            <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>

              <sensor>
               <xsl:value-of select=
                "format-number(
                               sum(/*/*/sensor
                                      [position() = $vPos]
                                           [number(.) = number(.)])
                              div
                               count(/*/*/sensor
                                        [position() = $vPos]
                                             [number(.) = number(.)]),
                               '0.00'
                               )
               "/>
              </sensor>
           </xsl:for-each>
         </timestamp>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (borrowed from @TimC):

```
<timestamps>
    <timestamp>
        <sensor>1.1</sensor>
        <sensor>2.3</sensor>
    </timestamp>
    <timestamp>
        <sensor>1.2</sensor>
        <sensor>2.2</sensor>
    </timestamp>
    <timestamp>
        <sensor>1.9</sensor>
        <sensor>NaN</sensor>
    </timestamp>
</timestamps>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<timestamp>
   <sensor>1.40</sensor>
   <sensor>2.25</sensor>
</timestamp>
```

Comment: "hardcoding" the different sensors is not feasible, because I have usually 10 up to 24 sensors in one XML file... this would lead to a lot of ugly redundancy in the XSLT file. Sorry, I've simplified the example a lot....

Comment: Aaaah, the consolidation shall work for each 60s toward 1 minute, so starting after 60 input timestamps again averaging a new minutes value - this got also lost due to my too much simplified example, sorry.

Comment: @Achim: I updated my answer. The transformation now works with any number of sensors.

Comment: It don't consolidate 60 old timestamps into 1 new, currently it simply go over all inputs

Comment: @Achim: Where have you stated this new requirement? I see it for the first time.

Comment: Sorry this was in since beginning, it was only a little bit bad phrased, now the text is clearer. I simply have thousands of measurements, one per second, which shall be merged into one per minute.I've already tried to introduce the grouping by 60 - but - what a hell this XSLT is too complex for my brain, I didn't achived it so far

Comment: @Achim: Please, edit the question and provide appropriate XML document (with more than 60 samples) and the exact wanted result -- it's wrong to leave people guessing.